# Check if window.matchMedia is executed from page load or from browser resizing

Tags: javascript

I use this piece of code to attach a Listener to the window and to detect when the width of the page is narrower than 992 px.

```
if (matchMedia) {
    const mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 992px)");
    mq.addListener(WidthChange);
    WidthChange(mq);
}

// media query change
function WidthChange(mq) {
    if (!mq.matches) {
        document.getElementById('site-navigation').classList.remove('toggled');
    }
}
```

My problem is that the WidthChange function is executed also when the page was just loaded. Is there a way to match only the case when the browser has been resized ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `matchMedia` is `true` (I guess when the screen is narrower than 992px) `WidthChange(mq);` will always be called on load.

Don't call it directly but only add it as a listener.

```js
if (matchMedia) {
    const mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 992px)");
    mq.addListener(WidthChange);
    // WidthChange(mq);
}

// media query change
function WidthChange(mq) {
    if (!mq.matches) {
        document.getElementById('site-navigation').classList.remove('toggled');
    }
}
```